# change key values of map

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components

I am having data in Map which is like:

```
Map<string, List<string>> mapRecord = new Map<string,List<string>>();
```

In key I am storing the account name and in value i have List of string. i need to convert the key value from account name to account id in this map later .
means i need to create a new map with same values but this time key should be account id instead of account name

```
Map<id, List<string>> mapRecord = new Map<id,List<string>>();
```

please provide any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create new map of Account name => Id

```
Map<String,Id> accNametoIdMap = new <String,Id>();
```

put all values in `accNametoIdMap`  when required

To copy data from 'mapRecord' to new Map of `Map<Id, List<string>>`, use below code

```
Map<Id, List<string>> mapRecordWithId = new Map<Id,List<string>>();

for(String accName: mapRecord.keySet()){
    List<String> tempList = mapRecord.get(accName);
    Id accid = accNametoIdMap.get(accName);
    mapRecordWithId.put(accid,tempList);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Set of keys in Map is read-only,  and you can't do changes to keys like `mapRecord.keySet().add(something)`. So you can create new Map with new keys and same values.

---

in current case you have to match old keys (names) and new keys (ids). Lets say all account names are **unique** in your org, and you have already populated `Map` `mapRecord` so you can do the following:

```
// map to store account Name - account Id pairs
Map<String, Id> accountIdsByNameMap = new Map<String, Id>();

//query accounts to get their ids
List<Account> accounts = [
    select Id, Name
    from Account
    where Name in :mapRecord.keySet()
    ];

//fill map to get  account Id by its Name
for(Account acc :accounts){
    accountIdsByNameMap.put(acc.Name, acc.Id);
}

Map<Id, List<String>> mapRecordResult = new Map<Id,List<String>>();
//
for(String accountName :mapRecord.keySet()){
    Id accountId = accountIdsByNameMap.get(accountName);
    mapRecordResult.put(accountId, mapRecord.get(accountName));
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much , i understand the concept now.